# need to count constants names in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have a list of `constant` objects as shown below. They are 
`record` type. I am trying to run a `loop` in which I can access all of them one by one. Could somebody suggest a way to do that?

```
type objecttype is record
      id, x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end : integer;
end record objecttype;   
constant C_OBJ1: objecttype :=(id       =>   0,
                               x_start  => 200,
                               x_end    => 300);
constant C_OBJ2: objecttype :=(id       =>   0,
                              x_start  => 400,
                              x_end    => 500);
```

I want to do  something like :

`for i in 0 to 5 loop
    C_OBJ(i).........
 end loop;`

Comment: by the way, because you are defining a constant, you need to specify all elements in the object: so also `y_start` and `y_end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array of objects. E.g.:

```
entity test_e is
end entity;

architecture test_a of test_e is
    type objecttype is record
        id, x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end : integer;
    end record objecttype;   

    type objectarray is array (natural range <>) of objecttype;

    constant C_OBJ : objectarray(0 to 5) := (
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        );
begin
end architecture;
```

Comment: @user3094049 I find it quite interesting that you know how to define records (rarely done in the field), but not how to define arrays (very common). How come?

Comment: I knew how to define arrays, but it did not strike me in this case that an array would solve the problem. I am new to VHDL programming

Answer (score 0):

IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 para 1 (in part):

> An array object is a composite object consisting of elements that have the same subtype. The name for an element of an array uses one or more index values belonging to specified discrete types. ...

The key here is that all your record named elements are of the same type.

The use of a record type here might stem from an object oriented paradigm (using field names to convey meaning which should really be user defined attributes in VHDL but are not synthesis eligible).

Create an enumerated index type for an array type and an
an array type using the index type:

```
package foo is
    type indx is (id, x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end);
    type objecttype is array (indx range id to y_end) of integer;
    constant C_OBJ1: objecttype := (id       =>   0,
                                    x_start  => 200,
                                    x_end    => 300,
                                    y_start  => 0,
                                    y_end    => 0);
    constant C_OBJ2: objecttype := (id       =>   0,
                                    x_start  => 400,
                                    x_end    => 500,
                                    y_start  => 0,
                                    y_end    => 0);
end package foo;

use work.foo.all; 
entity fum is
end entity;

architecture fie of fum is
begin
    process
    begin
        for i in objecttype'range loop
            report "C_OBJ1(" & indx'image(i) & ") = " &
                 integer'image(C_OBJ1(i));
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Note the predefined attribute `'image` works with any scalar type (including discrete types) or subtype and an enumerated type qualifies. The loop parameter range is that of an object of an array type.

And this gives:

> ghdl -r fum
>   fum.vhdl:25:13:@0ms:(report note): C_OBJ1(id) = 0
>   fum.vhdl:25:13:@0ms:(report note): C_OBJ1(x_start) = 200
>   fum.vhdl:25:13:@0ms:(report note): C_OBJ1(x_end) = 300
>   fum.vhdl:25:13:@0ms:(report note): C_OBJ1(y_start) = 0
>   fum.vhdl:25:13:@0ms:(report note): C_OBJ1(y_end) = 0

when run.

It also implies you would access the elements of an array as indexed names instead of selected names:  C_OBJ1(id), C_OBJ1(x_start), ...

You can convert indx type values to/from an integer type with the predefined attributes `'pos` and `'val`.

Comment: I guess `type objecttype is array (indx) of integer;` would be sufficient, unless you want a restricted range. Accepted by both Modelsim and GHDL.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.1 *constrained_array_definition ::=
array index_constraint of element_subtype_indication*,  *index_constraint ::= ( discrete_range { , discrete_range } )*, *discrete_range ::= discrete_subtype_indication | range*., 6.3 Subtype declarations *subtype_indication ::=
[ resolution_indication ] type_mark [ constraint ]* (where type_mark is indx). The same thing for the loop parameter (10.10 Loop statement *parameter_specification ::= identifier* **in** *discrete_range*. If you were only sure by trying how illustrative is using a subtype indication?

Comment: You can also use a subtype indication to provide a discrete range in a slice name (8.5) *slice_name ::= prefix ( discrete_range )*, great for defining fields in arrays.

Comment: Because -like most people- I don't know IEEE1076-2008 by hart, or always have access to it. And even if I had, I consider it very hard to read. Just look at the part you quoted: each definition there requires you to look up more definitions. And often the definitions are language-specific. I know what I know mostly by experience. But since I'm switching languages multiple times a day, I need to verify my code using compilers, to be sure I don't make a mistake.

Comment: Somewhere there's a BNF (syntax) in HTML, cross linked you can wander through it by clicking. The standard can be easier to read if you understand what it says, and why. The syntax summary in Annex C has section references to find semantics, all a bit easier in the PDF file with links. VHDL is a [formal notation](http://www.rbjones.com/rbjpub/methods/fm/fm022.htm) useful for formal proofs (for synthesis eligible VHDL). It implies the language is described self-referentially (yes the definitions are language specific).